Where does a Mac get the configuration to mount volumes from?
The /etc/fstab is empty and I know I can still use it, but I am trying to find where a specific line item in the mount output is configured.
Btw, /etc/auto_master is also empty
I installed Circuitpython at one point and removed it. However, the Circuitpython volume still gets mounted every time and I'm unable to find where that is configured. I had already deleted the directory where circuit python was installed, so it's not that.
However, the system should not be getting these mount suggestions from random places there has to be a replacement for /etc/fstab. Can you tell me what it is?
Here is the output of mount I am concerned about --
/dev/disk1s6 on /Volumes/CircuitPython (APFS, local, journaled)

Clearly, it's configured somewhere but I am at my wits end finding that place.
EDIT: I am trying to stop the system from mounting CircuitPython but am unable to figure out where it's getting the configuration settings from.

Is there an alias for the volume in your login items?  How did you "remove" it?  If that's a real volume on the disk, why wouldn't the OS mount it?

What version of macOS are you running?

@MarcWilson it's not clear what you mean. I am looking for help to "NOT" mount it.  The system keep mounting CircuitPython from somewhere which I am unable to figure out. The login items is empty. Circuitpython is just an app that I removed from Applications

@Allan am using a really old version -- 10.15.7

I glanced through the documentation, there's no separate partitioning step that I see.  Did you create this volume yourself with Disk Utility?  Please add to your question the output of diskutil list.

At the moment it is unclear where the volume resides. We can't see whether it's on an internal disk partition (in which case Marc's first comment is correct, macOS would mount all available local volumes), or whether it's a left-over DMG file from when you installed CircuitPython. A DMG mount will survive a logout / login, but won't survive a reboot. In addition to providing the output to diskutil list, how did you install CircuitPython, and then exactly how did you remove it?
